# Refresh Powershell Instance / Session

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'll preface this by saying I am not an expert powershell user by any means, so I'm probably going about this the wrong way.

I have a module that I am working on regularly and I update / tweak it often. It is stored in `C:\Users\-user-\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` if that matters.

Currently I have to close the powershell window and reopen a new one if I want the new / updated methods to be accessible - even when I perform an import in the same window that I am executing commands in.

I have tried doing `. $profile` but this does nothing. Do I need to add the module to the profile?

Comment: `Remove-Module moduleName -Force; Import-Module moduleName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to removing and adding the module would be simply `Import-Module myModule -Force`:

> -Force [< SwitchParameter >]
>
> Indicates that this cmdlet re-imports a module and its members, even if the module or its members
>       have an access mode of read-only.

Comment: Worked a charm! Thanks @ManuelBatsching

Answer (score 1):

You can simply unload the module and then load it again.

As we can see in Microsoft's documentation:

**Remove-Module**

> The Remove-Module cmdlet removes the members of a module, such as
>   cmdlets and functions, from the current session.

**Import-Module**

> The Import-Module cmdlet adds one or more modules to the current
>   session. The modules that you import must be installed on the local
>   computer or a remote computer.

Here's a code for example:

```
# Unload the Module
PS > Remove-Module myModule -Force

# Load it again
PS > Import-Module myModule
```